# Problem with swagger array of objects: validation error: None is not of type 'array'

Tags: python, swagger, connexion

I'm trying to make REST API with connexion but can't figure out how to set up get operation that consumes an array of objects. In the end, I need to get information about several items at once.

Using Python 3.7, connexion-2.3.0 and Swagger with OpenAPI Specification ver. 2.

**My swagger file:**

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "This is documentation for REST api test."
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: test

consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json

basePath: /api

paths:
  /test:
    get:
      operationId: test.test
      summary: "Just testing array."

      parameters:
        - name: query
          in: body
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/query'

      responses:
        200:
          description: All ok!

definitions:
  query:
      type: object

      required:
        - a
        - b

      properties:
        a:
          type: integer
          description: "Test propertie 1."
          example: 42

        b:
          type: string
          description: "Test propertie 2."
          example: "hi"

        c:
          type: string
          description: "Test propertie 3."
          example: "abc"
```

**My Python file with test function:**

```py
def test(query):
    for item in query:
        print(item)

    return {'result': 'it is fine'}
```

**Trying to pass JSON through Swagger UI:**

```
[
  {
    "a": 42,
    "b": "hi",
    "c": "abc"
  }
]
```

**Expected response from my test function:**

```
{
  "result": "it is fine"
}
```

**Actual response:**

```
{
  "detail": "None is not of type 'array'",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "type": "about:blank"
}
```

Comment: The path operation is `get` - should it be `post` maybe? GET requests are not really supposed to have a request body.

Comment: @Helen Thanks! Looks like problem indeed in get operation, if I change it to post everything works fine. But I don't sure why I can't use a request body with get. I need to get information about several items at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the **GET** verb, you can not use **body**. You should use something like that :

```py
      parameters:
        - name: objects
          in: query
          required: true
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
```

The array itens must be of types : string , number, integer, boolean or array

Comment: Can't I put there an array of type: object? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: using get ? I dont get it